# Display column values only once

Tags: sql, sql-server

Supposed that I have the following table. How to display 'amount' only once based on column `ID` ?

```
   ID     Amount 
    1      10.00  
    1      10.00  
    1      10.00  
    2      10.00
    2      10.00
    2      10.00
```

Given the ff example the expected output should be like this :

```
   ID     Amount 
    1      10.00  
    1      0.00  
    1      0.00  
    2      10.00
    2      0.00
    2      0.00
```

I tried using `ROW_NUMBER` but its not sufficient, its giving me this result.

```
   ID     Amount 
    1      10.00  
    1      0.00  
    1      0.00  
    2      0.00
    2      0.00
    2      0.00
```

EDIT : 
This is what i tried so far :

```
SELECT ID
       ,CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Amount ORDER BY ID) = 1  
            THEN Amount
            ELSE 0.00
        END [AMOUNT]
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Hi @dasblinkenlight i'd updated my question. thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change your partition to use ID:

```
SELECT ID
       ,CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) = 1  
            THEN Amount
            ELSE 0.00
        END [AMOUNT]
FROM TABLE
Order by ID, Amount Desc
```

Comment: nice, i haven't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
select id, iif(id=lag(id,1,0), 0, amount) from mytable order by id
```

basically, if the current id is the same as the id one row back, use 0.  otherwise, use the amount column.

I am assuming, from the data you have provided, that "amount" stays the same for any single id.

Comment: is execution time fast? im dealing with large data.

Comment: does not add any significant cost.  Sql Server keeps the last row in memory anyway.

Comment: thanks for the effort bro, really appreciated. im satisfied with @APH answer cheers!

Comment: That is likely to cost more on performance, depending on your data, but the cost difference might be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

For those that "hate" OVER and PARTITION, but it's good to learn, you can use the ID of a LEFT JOIN table to determine whether to display the data or not.

So using the OPs' example, lets' assume `ID` is from `TableA`, and `Amount` is from `TableB`, both linked using their respective unique `ID`.

**TableA**

```
ID INT Primary Key 
ColA some column 
ColB some column
```

**TableB**

```
ID INT Primary Key 
Amount FLOAT 
ColA some column 
etc
```

Then this SELECT should also work:

```
SELECT a.ID,
       CASE WHEN b.ID IS NULL
            THEN b.Amount
            ELSE 0.00
       END [AMOUNT]
FROM TableA AS a
    LEFT JOIN TableB AS b
```

It certainly avoids sorting dilemmas with OVERS, as they can play *stranger things* when the data is sorted in a different way.